# clang/llvm ARM instrinics

Tags: clang, llvm, intrinsics

Where can I find a complete list of intrinsics supported by clang/llvm targeting ARM? Everything I can dig up has to do with NEON, but what if I want to do something like a bit scan or a rotate?

*Side question*: Are the intrinsics supported by clang or llvm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning on getting into ARM asm, I would really suggest that you just skip any use of intrinsics. It seems like a nice idea, just mix your C and asm. But, in actual practice it will save you time and many headaches by just writing a whole function in ASM and the calling it like a normal C function. You can create a dummy C function and then have clang generate the ASM for it as an example of how parameters are passed in and returned. I wrote up many more details and a working example iOS xcode project [here](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post10_arm_timing_framework/index.html) along with code that you can use to do timing of different ASM implementations. Also note that while ARM code works across different versions of ARM CPUs, newer 64 bit ARM stuff is quite different.

Comment: Dead link-any way to update?

Answer (score 1):

I have irritatingly never been able to find documentation for this.  However, you can find the declarations in the clang code here (found by searching "clang __builtin_arm")

http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/include/clang/Basic/BuiltinsARM.def?view=markup

Comment: Dead link-any way to update?